# getting error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting values from mysql query  as an object so I checked with `print_r($result);` and got like this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [user_name] => user1,user2,user3,user4
)
```

if I  try to do like this

```
echo $result['user_name'];
```

then  getting error

> "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

what should be the correct way to echo **user1,user2,user3** values

Comment: try `echo $result->user_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an array of objects

```
stdClass Object
(
    [user_name] => user1,user2,user3,user4
)
```

then try to show data like this

```
echo $result->user_name;
```

When associative array without objects

```
Array ( [user_name] => user1, user2, user3, user4 )
```

Do like this

```
echo $result['user_name'];
```

Comment: @Anonymous your welcome. Accept the answer if it suits you